# how to affect to a string a special characters

Tags: c#

I have to affect  special characters to a string variable  like `\*` or `"""` or `''` 
I remarked that the comment worked very well because they are contained in "" so they are considered like string.The problem is how i can i force that `"""` will be considered as string .

my code:

```
if (line.StartsWith("/*") || line.StartsWith("""""));
```

or

```
string a= """""
```

help me please

Comment: Use '\' instead of '/'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes:

```
line.StartsWith("\"\"\"")
```

The `\` acts as an *escape character*, which prevents the quote from ending the string, and treats it instead as an embedded quotation character.